# android - force close, stop the app altogether

Tags: android

Our app is working great until we shut down the phone. When we power it back on the app comes up but the buttons and anything else are not responding to anything. I a, thinking its because we are not killing the app altogether when the phone shuts down. How to properly do that?  How to force the app to shut down properly when the phone is being shut down?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem almost certainly lies elsewhere as the kernel will fully close any apps you have running when you shut the phone down.

Comment: @dropsOfJupiter:  Sorry but there is no way to know what your issue is.  I have no idea what your code is or does, for one ...